# How to use few methods inside of asynchronous methods?

Tags: javascript, html, automated-tests, cypress

In the Cypress I want to create a method that will run other methods if condition will be fine.

Code:

```
sizeOfTableShouldBeChangedAfterResizingIfThereAreManyData() {
    cy.get('.footerWrapper').then(div => {
        if(div.find('.pagination').length) {
            cy.get('.pagination > .page').its('length').then(numberOfPages => {
                if(numberOfPages > 3) {
                    this.numberOfRowsShouldBeEqualAtLeast(10)
                    this.changeNumberOfDisplayedRowsByIndex(1)
                    this.numberOfRowsShouldBeEqualAtLeast(20)
                    this.changeNumberOfDisplayedRowsByIndex(0)
                    this.numberOfRowsShouldBeEqualAtLeast(10)

                    return this
                }
            })
        } 
    })
    return this
}
```

From Cypress I got a message:

```
CypressError: cy.then() failed because you are mixing up async and sync code.

In your callback function you invoked 1 or more cy commands but then returned a synchronous value.

Cypress commands are asynchronous and it doesn't make sense to queue cy commands and yet return a synchronous value.

You likely forgot to properly chain the cy commands using another cy.then().

The value you synchronously returned was: '{}'
```

I read a documentation from:

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/overview/why-cypress.html#In-a-nutshell

But I am not sure how it should be written to works correctly. After this method, I want to call other ones synchronously.

Does anyone have any ideas how could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved a problem by myself, first return wasn't actually needed and it caused problems :-)